# <input type="email" placeholder="E-mailAddress"> not working because of special characters in a placeholder attribute

Tags: html

its now not working fine showing uncaught syntax error '-' in console.

On submitting the form page refreshes and form not submitted.
What we can use if we want to allow any special charactes in a placeholder attribute of this field?

Comment: Please include the code snippet inside your post (not in the title) and use the "JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet" button.

Answer (score 0):

it works. i still use. you can see this

```html
<input type="email" placeholder="-123_+*">
```